# Styling <asp:Button /> with CSS

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css

I have a asp:Button, I used css styles with cssClass property in asp:Button, but those styles are not working.

This is my asp button:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="form_row">
             <asp:Button ID="ButtonSend" CssClass="BtnSend" runat="server" Text="Send" OnClick="ButtonSend_Click" />
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.BtnSend {
  width: 53px;
  height: 24px;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  background: url(../../Images/contact_bt.gif) no-repeat center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

If I'm not wrong, I should use something like this:

```
input[type="submit"]
{
 //css coding
}
```

but I don't know where to put it and how to affect only this button.

Comment: How does the buttons html look like when rendered in browser?

Comment: <input type="submit" ... value="Send"... class="BtnSend" /> here it is.

Comment: Use `.BtnSend` and add it in your css file.

Comment: Your css seems to be working fine. [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/xzXhd/). You'll see your button on the top right corner. That's what your css tells it to do.

Comment: Yes but the button still looks like a default button because the background: url(../../Images/contact_bt.gif) no-repeat center; is an image with rounded corners which is not showing them. It looks like an image inside a default button without rounded corners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, add/change this in your css:

```
.BtnSend {
  border: none;
  background: transparent url(../../Images/contact_bt.gif) no-repeat center;
}
```